# How to blur the view except the label (swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, label, blur

I searched the web and found only how to blur the whole view or specific area in the view. 
If i got a small image/label in the middle of the screen, how do I blur everything "behind" him, but not him?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create the subview Which will overlap a particular part of your view and wont be blurred:

```
var View = (frame: CGRectMake(<x: CGFloat>, <y: CGFloat>, <width: CGFloat>, <height: CGFloat>))
View.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
View.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
self.view.addSubview(View)
```

And than create the subview of label

```
descLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
descLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica", size: 12.0)
descLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0);
descLabel.numberOfLines = 0
descLabel.text = "No Description was found"
descLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
descLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
View.addSubview(descLabel)
```